# Chrome not calculating width correctly for block with overflow: hidden, left margin, and floated element to the left

Tags: google-chrome, css-float

I've come across a bug in Chrome in the following situation:

- Two block elements (we'll call them `#rail` and `#well`)
- `#rail` is floated left
- `#well` is not floated, has an overflow set (`hidden` or `auto`), and a left margin set.

What I'm observing is that, in Chrome, `#well` is not as wide as it should be. From playing with the different widths, it appears that Chrome is calculating the width of the `#well` as if neither the margin, nor the available space it inhabits, exists. Here's a reduction:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                width: 1000px;
                font-size: 2em;
                color: white;
            }

            #container {
                background-color: green;
            }

            #rail {
                float: left;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: blue;
            }

            #well {
                overflow: hidden;
                margin-left: 500px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="rail">RAIL</div>
            <div id="well">WELL</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Screen shots of the reduction in Chrome and Firefox attached. In Firefox, it's as expected -- 100px of `#rail`, then 400px of margin, then 500px of `#well`.

So I'm wondering if anyone's seen this before and, if so, whether there's a known workaround. Here's why I have this combination of properties:

1. The `#well` contains floated content that I'd like for it to wrap, hence the `overflow`.
2. The `#rail` may or may not exist on the page, hence the left margin on the `#well`.

Many thanks for any pointers!

Here it is in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

And in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478978/margin-behavior-of-overflowhidden-div-after-floating-div-on-webkit

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `margin-right:-500px` to `#well`

I had the same problem and your reduction helped me solve it.

Comment: Well, this works if you know how much width ´#well´ shall have, but then you will not have that problem anyway, because you can just set the width... or am I missiong something? I am having problems with this as well, because I need the width to be set right dynamically, because I have several elements with different contents, which are floating.