# Strange CSS3 Button

Tags: html, css

My CSS3 buttons aren't displaying correctly in certain use cases. In FF & Safari they display fine but in Chrome the left hand border is thicker and when you hover over them, the fill colour doesn't fill 100% of the area. See a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3x4zc8tq/3/ How can I fix it?

```
/* @group Center all the things */

.center-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

    .center-wrapper .center {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
                transform: translateY(-50%);


       /* This fixes the blurred buttons but breaks centering

       -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
               backface-visibility: hidden;

       transform: translateZ(0);*/
     }

/* @end */
```

Tried and tested methods such as below do not work for me:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: Nice effect. Not seeing any issues with Chrome here though. You aren't zoomed in by any chance are you? Try pressing `CTRL` + `0` to make sure.

Comment: look fine. which version of chrome you are using?

Comment: No problem in Chrome, but in Safari the button doesn't fill all the way up.

Comment: The only way I was able to recreate your issue in Chrome was by zooming out a few times.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm on Chrome 43.0.2357.65 (64-bit) and I'm zoomed 100%. Weird. I've not see the Safari issue though @Rvervuurt

Comment: I can confirm that this strange behaviour is also happening in my Chrome. Not zoomed in, no plugins or addons.

Comment: Maybe retina screen causing this?

Comment: If I zoom out at 90% the buttons look good but go back to 100% and I see the issue again.

Comment: I'm on a 2011 iMac, no retina for me

Comment: @darthmaim : how come? there are no images.

Comment: Zoom lessthan 75% then issue comes.

Comment: Have you tried positioning the elements rather than transforming them?

Comment: Check the effect I get in Safari here: http://i.imgur.com/lI8ysRf.png

Comment: The issue is a combination of all your translates and odd viewport widths. When the viewport has an even width, the buttons get rendered correctly. Chrome snaps the element to device pixels and is rounding something incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an incredibly strange issue for me but it appears as though, like most other commenters have stated, that it is indeed a Chrome issue.**

I needed to eradicate this problem completely so ended up using `max-width` to overcome it, which does have its own drawbacks. For example, if the button label is too long then it shall go on two lines and if its too short the button will look overly wide but they're compromises I'm happier with compared to the border and hover issues I was experiencing. Here's the working fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/3x4zc8tq/11/

Lets hope Google sort this...

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this to your CSS rule for `.btn::before`

```
.btn::before {
    left:-1px;
    width:101%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3x4zc8tq/6/

Comment: How can it cause the problem for you in Chrome? There's no way it can cause the problem described, it's entirely the opposite.

Comment: Doesn't appear to cause me a problem in IE or Chrome, please unvote.

Comment: Added compensation for that.

Comment: I can't see how it can work for some of us, but not others, and some of us don't see the original issue at all, where some do...

Comment: This fixes the left border issue but I still see the hover issue in that it still doesn't fill 100% of the button

Comment: It does if you increase the width like I added, worked fine across my multiple browsers

Comment: Interestingly, after checking your fiddle, it appears the buttons look and work fine for the bottom 2 blocks but the hover issue is still present for the vertically centred (pink) block.

Comment: Then I'd maybe look at other's suggestions, and look at other bits in your code, because it sounds like there's something that's really screwing things up. This issue seems to be far too flaky and inconsistent for it to be easily solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `overflow: hidden` of you anchor element on `.btn` to `overflow: auto`. `overflow: hidden` seems to add some margin. See more here:

[Margin behavior of "overflow:hidden" div after floating div on webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478978/margin-behavior-of-overflowhidden-div-after-floating-div-on-webkit)

[Overflow:hidden messing with margins in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988451/overflowhidden-messing-with-margins-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: I can't see any changes to your answer, unless I'm missing something?! highly likely :-|

Comment: Lol, sorry my browser stuck! investigating and updating soon.

Comment: Thats removed both issues with the border and hover, however in FF (and I'd assume IE) scrollbars now appear when you hover over the buttons...so very close

Comment: what if instead of `overflow: auto` you put  `overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;` (on .btn class) . try that.

Comment: Bugger. See http://jsfiddle.net/3x4zc8tq/10/ The border is fixed but the hover is still the problem after implementing overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: really? it does seem to work for me. Tried Chrome, FF and FF Dev Edition. Not tested in IE though.

Comment: After some resizing of the browser, it appears that its a Chrome percentage problem as what other commenters have said. Some widths work others do not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your issue is caused by the `text-align: center` property on your `block` element.

You can fix this issue by replacing:

```
.btn, .btn:visited, input.wpcf7-submit {
    display: inline-block;
}

with

.btn, .btn:visited, input.wpcf7-submit {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

Here is a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x4zc8tq/7/) 
Let me know if this is causing issues in other browsers

Comment: This fixes Chrome but breaks Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

First at all this is clearly a crhome bug.

However the problem with the right border may be easily "fix" (even if it's not broken) adding to your `::before` `opacity:0` and in your `hover::before`, `opacity:1`.

The problem with the black background not filling the full width seems to me like a bug related with the use of `transform: translateZ(0);` AND `z-index:1`in the same class. If you remove both it will fix it, however you will lost some of your effects... but maybe you could try another way to make the same.

Comment: The opacity thing is a good idea but it doesn't solve the entire issue. Removing translate z and z-index doesn't fix the hover issue either, all it does is remove the right hand border (oddly) but the background still doesn't fill 100% of the width